# Conversion of .dae to .glb / .gltf

Tags: xcode, blender, gltf, collada, usdz

I am having success converting .usdz models to .dae using Xcode.  However I eventually want the file formats to end up as .glb / .gltf.

I'm using blender to encode .dae into .glb, also a tool made by Khronos group here. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/COLLADA2GLTF

The problem is that the Xcode .dae output is a .dae file and a folder of .png texture files.  Xcode can read this just fine and reconstitute the original .dae however blender seems to be incapable of using these texture files and same with the Khronos CLI converter.  Using these tools, the .dae shows up without textures, colorless and only constituted in shape based on 3D coordinates.

Does anybody know how to use this folder of texture .png files to render color to a blender .dae?

Ultimately I want to convert .usdz to .glb / .gltf and this is the way I have found, but I'm running into this hiccup.  Google search did not improve the hiccup, hence my question here.

[image: .dae with .png textures in a folder]

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting and have found another way you can possibly do the conversion to GLB outside of Blender.  Basically, as you have found you convert the .usdz to .dae using Xcode - which results in a .dae file with a folder of textures (.png's).  If you now zip the file and the folder together - rename the .zip file ending to .zae.  Now take this .zae zip file and go to https://products.aspose.app/3d/conversion  you can convert the zip file to GLB.  Once you have the GLB file, test it out in Scene Viewer and you should now have the colours, textures etc. on the  model. I have had a few issues on one model, namely not all the textures seem to be there, majority are but a few more detailed elements are missing.  ie. I have a 3D Framed Artwork model, the black shiny frame, the brown paper backing, and the art colour background are fine but the details of the artwork are missing!  Very weird.  The Artwork itself is just in one texture file as a .png together with the other files for metallic, colours, etc. and it shows correctly in photoshop or viewer. Also the DAE file shows correctly in preview. Just when it's all brought together in GLB it is missing some detail.  Kind of 80% sorted though.  Hope this is of help!!  And I also hope I have saved another fellow human being from tearing out the remainder of their hair...lol

Comment: Update: just discovered the reason for missing detail on artwork image texture - using Reality Composer to create 3D model & convert to .usdz - frame models you can use to create 3D art by adding image.  This works fine for .usdz but you have to tweak a little to get it to work correctly in .glb once converted from.usdz via .dae - by adding an image overlay to the frame model and not just using the integrated image placeholder to add the image.  Works beautifully now! Good job as I have tons to do - check out an example here: https://wizhez.co.uk/product/rainbow-snow-leopard-framed-art-print

Comment: Also need to tweak the model viewer code a bit as I need it to be vertical placement in AR - the ar-placement="wall" doesn't seem to correctly the default setting of "floor" hmmm....may also turn off the auto spin !!

Comment: One last thing - you may not actually have to change the .zip file ending to .zae as it appears to work both with and without...